# Config files are "reset" on computer restart for Docker/Kitematic on Windows

Tags: docker, kitematic, docker-for-windows

I am currently running Docker on Windows 10 Pro with Docker for Windows and Kitematic.

I have setup all my containers and mounted the appropriate volumes. As soon as I restart my computer, I lose all my "configs". For example, I had all of my Deluge and Sickrage setuped, but then lost everything.

Kitematic seems to remember all the ENV and Volumes and Ports for the containers however. It is as if whenever the container is "started", it regenerates a config file.